# C++ Account Creation Program Crashing

Tags: c++, function, crash, passwords, account

I am hitting a bit of a roadblock and don't know what to do. I am attempting to write a program that creates an account with username and password and stores it to a text file. However, while using the program and inputting the username and password data, the program crashes as it moves to the encryption function. Thank you for your time.

```
bool processNewAccount (string username, string password)
{
    ofstream outFile;
    string outFileName = "creds.txt";
    outFile.open(outFileName.c_str(), fstream::app);
    if (!outFile)
        return false;
    outFile << username << ":" << password << endl;
    outFile.close();
    return true;
}

void encrypt(string& s, int key)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
    {
        s[i] = (s[i] + key) % 127;
        if (s[i] < 33)
        {
            s[i] = s[i] + 33;
        }
    }
}

string createAccount()
{
    string firstName;
    string lastName;
    cout << "Creating an Account:" << endl;
    cout << "First Name: ";
    cin >> firstName;
    cout << "Last Name: ";
    cin >> lastName;
    cout << endl;
    string username;
    if (lastName.length() <5)
    {
        for (int i = 0; username.length() <5; i++)
            username = lastName + firstName.substr(0,i);
    }
    else
        username = lastName.substr(0,4) + firstName.at(0);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            username.at(i) = tolower(username[i]);
}

string createPass ()
{
    string password1;
    string password2;
        cout << "Create a Password that:" << endl << endl << "-Is at least 10 characters" << endl << "-Contains no spaces" << endl << endl << "Password: ";
        cin >> password1;
       if (password1.length() < 10)
        {
        cout << "Password is not secure enough" << endl;
        cout << "Enter a password at least 10 characters: " << endl << endl;
        createPass();
        }
        if (password1.length() >= 10)
        cout << "Confirm Password: ";
        cin >> password2;
        if (password2 != password1)
        { 
            cout << "Passwords do not match!" << endl << endl;
            createPass();
        }
}

int main()
{
    string user;
    string pass;
    char menuOption;
    do
    {

        printMenu();
        cin >> menuOption;
        switch (menuOption)
        {
            case '1': login();
                      break;
            case '2': 
                        user = createAccount();
                        pass = createPass();
                        encrypt(pass, 13);
                        processNewAccount (user, pass);
                        cout << "Welcome " << "Username: " << user << endl << "Email: " << user << "@student.edu" << endl;
                      break;
            case '3': break;
            default : cout << "\nInvalid entry. Please choose from the menu.|n";
                      break;
        }
    }
    while (menuOption != 3);

    cout << "\n Goodbye.\n\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is your input when it crashes?

Comment: Main problem I can see is that the `createPass` function does not return the password. I think your compiler was being generous in allowing that to compile.

Answer (score 2):

Neither `createAccount()` nor `createPass()` returns a value, despite having a non-`void` return type. This means your program has undefined behaviour. Likely the stack is in "a bit of a way" after calling those functions, resulting in the crash you've observed. Your compiler should have warned you about this: *heed your compiler's warnings*, then you'll know what to do.

Ensure that you have a `return` statement so that you can pass your functions' results back to the caller. These statements might look like this:

```
std::string createAccount()
{
   // ...

   return username;
}

std::string createPass()
{
   // ...

   return password1;
}
```

In the case of `createPass()`, you'll also have to change your recursive calls:

```
if (password1.length() < 10) {
   cout << "Password is not secure enough" << endl;
   cout << "Enter a password at least 10 characters: " << endl << endl;
   return createPass();
}

// ...

if (password2 != password1) { 
   cout << "Passwords do not match!" << endl << endl;
   return createPass();
}
```

… but I agree with John that you'd be better off replacing this recursion with [a nice loop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49058459/560648).

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better version of createPass. It actually returns the password, and also uses a loop to avoid the recursive calls that you make.

```
string createPass ()
{
    string password1;
    bool password_ok = false;
    do
    {
        cout << "Create a Password that:" << endl << endl << "-Is at least 10 characters" << endl << "-Contains no spaces" << endl << endl << "Password: ";
        cin >> password1;
        if (password1.length() < 10)
        {
            cout << "Password is not secure enough" << endl;
            cout << "Enter a password at least 10 characters: " << endl << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Confirm Password: ";
            string password2;
            cin >> password2;
            if (password2 != password1)
            { 
                cout << "Passwords do not match!" << endl << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                password_ok = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (!password_ok);
    return password1;
}
```

And as Lightness Races in Orbit points out you need to fix `createAccount` in a similar way.

Untested code of course.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your knowledge, I appreciate your help.

Comment: You appreciate it so much you vandalised your question and deleted your account